# How to re-orient triangle faces in three.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

*** Edited with better example ***

I use Three.js to display the hull of an MRI gastric image; the hull is loaded from an external file as vtk format. Here is a demonstration: http://www.menne-biomed.de/uni/3d/alphahull.html ; use space to toggle.

These are alpha-hulls computed from voxels as nicely three.js displayed in http://www.menne-biomed.de/uni/3d . I love these images. **Thanks a log, Mr.doob!!**

Example 1-3 are from an almost empty stomach; 4-6 are from a filled stomach.

(1) and (4) are single sided, to show that the triangles are inconsistently oriented in the vtk file.

(2) and (5) shows the problem this creates to when using doubleSided; the ugly patches are best seen on the flat side, where the stomach has been cut at the boundary of the MRI. I looks like the lighting is not symmetric on double-siding.

(3) and (6) are my workarounds: I use doubleSided=false, and have duplicated the Polygons with a different orientation: for example, 1 2 3 in the original was augmented by 1 3 2.

The solution works Ok for me, but I am not sure if there is an easier way out.

Comment: I think your vtk encoder is buggy. You seem to be creating double faces which is doesn't work well when calculating the normals of the vertices. If you want to see the faces from the two sides better use `mesh.doubleSided = true`.

Comment: These duplications were manually made by me, because they produce the picture I like. I have updated the example and the text to better show what I mean.

Comment: I kind of see what's going on... where are you getting these models from? The models I've found on the nets load fine with the VTKLoader and the face/vertex normals get computed properly. Seems like in these models the direction of each face is being alternated, not sure why. Is there something on the file format spec about this?

Comment: These models were produced by me from R and are the result of an alhpa hull calculation. I can live with the sandwich formulation I found. It would be better to have the faces correctly oriented; my question only came up when I realized that direct plotting with rgl give a good representation.

Comment: What seems to be happening is that you're alternating the direction (ClockWise, CounterClockWise) of each face. If you imagine a quad... you're doing this: 0 3 1 (CCW), 1 2 3 (CW) instead of: 0 3 1 (CCW), 1 3 2 (CCW). All the faces need to be constructed using CCW.

Comment: I know, that's why I switched the faces...

Comment: And the problem is still there?