# Some faces of a THREE.Mesh object are not displayed

Tags: shader, webgl, three.js

I use the three.js librairy to code in WebGL, and I would like use shaders. My objects are THREE.Mesh objects.

To use shaders I create three buffer to transmit to informations to shaders.

- VerticesArray which contains all vertices of the object.
- NormalsArray which contains all normals of points.
- IndicesArray which contains the rank of vertices in verticesArray.
  (faces are triangles, so three indices link three vertices of a same
  face).

To create theses array I do this :

```
 this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 15, 15 ),
            new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xF40029 } )
        );

    this.vertices = new Array();

    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.mesh.geometry.vertices.length ; i++){
        this.vertices.push(this.mesh.geometry.vertices[i].x);
        this.vertices.push(this.mesh.geometry.vertices[i].y);
        this.vertices.push(this.mesh.geometry.vertices[i].z);
    }

this.normals = new Array();

    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.mesh.geometry.faces.length ; i++){ 

            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].a*3] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[0].x;
            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].a*3+1] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[0].y;
            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].a*3+2] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[0].z;

            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].b*3] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[1].x;
            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].b*3+1] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[1].y;
            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].b*3+2] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[1].z;

            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].c*3] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[2].x;
            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].c*3+1] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[2].y;
            this.normals[this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].c*3+2] = this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[2].z;

    }

this.indices = new Array();

    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.mesh.geometry.faces.length ; i++){
        this.indices.push(this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].a);
        this.indices.push(this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].b);
        this.indices.push(this.mesh.geometry.faces[i].c);
    }

this.vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this.indices), gl.STREAM_DRAW);
    this.indexCount = this.indices.length;
```

At this step, I have a strange problem, on the display I can see my two subjects but some Faces are not displayed.

Do you have an idea to solve my problem ?

We can see my problem on the following picture.
I display two balls.
http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/1094/ballsk.jpg

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as

[How to re-orient triangle faces in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983473/how-to-re-orient-triangle-faces-in-three-js)

I have not found an easy solution to reorient the faces in three.js such that all are outward looking. My simple workaround would be to plot everything again with the opposite orientation.

For an example, see http://www.menne-biomed.de/uni/3d/alphahull.html